# sort in nested object array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{
  "_id": "5f8e51e188e8bc24ff8b85e4",
  "name": "stars",
  "players": [
    {
      "_id": "5f961d850965854110fce6a5",
      "name": "juliannn",
      "points": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f961dec0965854110fce6a6",
      "name": "Julian",
      "points": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f961df70965854110fce6a7",
      "name": "Matias",
      "points": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f961e070965854110fce6a8",
      "name": "Mariano",
      "points": 11
    }
  ],
  "description": "Pick 1 or more numbers that sum to the number of stars",
  "__v": 0
}
```

I have this collection of data that is being returned by this function

`const game = await Game.findOne({ name: id })`

And now I want to sort the players by the points DESC and what I did is

`const game = await Game.findOne({ name: id }).sort({'players.points': 1})`

that i get it from [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

What I'm expecting is this

```
{
  "_id": "5f8e51e188e8bc24ff8b85e4",
  "name": "stars",
  "players": [
    {
      "_id": "5f961e070965854110fce6a8",
      "name": "Mariano",
      "points": 11
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f961d850965854110fce6a5",
      "name": "juliannn",
      "points": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f961dec0965854110fce6a6",
      "name": "Julian",
      "points": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f961df70965854110fce6a7",
      "name": "Matias",
      "points": 0
    }
  ],
  "description": "Pick 1 or more numbers that sum to the number of stars",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregation to manupilate an array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "5f8e51e188e8bc24ff8b85e4"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$players"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "players.points": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      players: {
        $push: "$players"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3cZVjh5yQjg)**